# How to exclude Ramp Up and Ramp Down period values in Jmeter Analysis

Tags: performance, jmeter, listener

I have been performing load execution which simulates users concurrently.
However, I don't need the data for the entire run. I need the data during the peak period only.

Can anyone suggest a listener or any method which will provide me the data for a specific period excluding the data of the Ramp Up and Ramp Down period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

1. If you look into 1st line of your .jtl result file you'll see something like:

   > **1403191911666**,38,Dummy Sampler,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,0,0

   Where first column is current time stamp in milliseconds from [Unix Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) start

   So if you move out 3 last digits you'll get test start timestamp in seconds.
2. If your ramp-up is i.e. 300 seconds, just add 300 * 1000 to it and trim your results file to start with `1403192211XXX`
3. Do the same for last N lines depending on your ramp-down time.
4. Analyze trimmed .jtl file as usual

**Option 2**

Use free [Blazemeter Listener](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-analyze-load-test-results-using-new-blazemeter-listener) to analyze your test results online, it has:

1. Possibility to limit time frame to "interesting" slot
2. Possibility to compare different test runs results

Hope this helps.

Comment: `Option 2` is not available at the moment? Given [link](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-analyze-load-test-results-using-new-blazemeter-listener) is not working

Comment: It should be [still available](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/sense-uploader/BlazeMeterUploader.md), also there is [Taurus tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation) which provides [interactive console and web reports](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Reporting/)